# Software installed in ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, software-sources

I have a software installed in ubuntu in my PC.
Can i make a .deb or .tar.bz2 file of this software from here so that i can install this software in another machine without having internet connection?

Comment: What's the software you're trying to install?

Comment: He's not trying to install any software, he wants to create a .deb or .tar from an installed program to install on another device! Haven't your read the question @mitch ?

Comment: @Alvar I read the question, and if I want to answer I want to know what is the software, so I'd know how to handle dependencies installing on the other machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the .deb files of packages that you have installed in the folder /var/cache/apt.

If you had another Ubuntu machine with the same version, you could copy over the contents of /var/cache/apt to that machine and then try to run sudo apt-get install packagename and it would try to pull them from the apt cache. I would definitely not recommend this unless you are using the same version of Ubuntu on both machines.

Comment: in theory this would work if the computers were on the same system version and both were up to date. But has it been tested to work?

Comment: I have done it before, but it was in a very controlled environment: I had just installed Ubuntu on two machines, pulled a few hundred packages from the internet on to one of them, and then SCP'd over the whole directory. However, both computers were connected to the internet, I just wanted to save time.

But also, the only problem that I can see emerging is that some packages were previously removed from the cache of computer #1 (the internet-connected one), in which case it would try to pull them from the network and fail. You would need to be careful about dependencies, but it should work.